# contract reference another contract, what ABI information needed?

Tags: contract-development

To reference another contract, the ABI is easily included like this. What information needs to be there? The function name, I guess, what about accessability such as public/private/internal/external/pure/view, or if it returns a type and what it returns? Asking for what is needed, not so much what looks good or makes it more human readable.

```
contract A { function foo() public returns (uint) {} }

contract B {

    A a = A();
```

Comment: Needed: function name, function access-level, type of each input argument, type of the return-value. Not needed: name of each input argument, name of the return-value.

Comment: thanks! why is function access-level needed?

Comment: to clarify, to call a function on a contract, the name of the function _needs_ to be known, for the function signature, same with type of each input argument, and for the return value, I think I see how that needs to be known as well (manual calls with bytes4(keccak256(“foo(uint256)”)) cannot take return values without assembly "hack"), but, function access-level, I do not see why it is needed or what it does

Answer (score 1):

You just need an interface for the contract that you want to reference.
Just add the functions prototype and you're good to go.

**Example**

```
contract ERC20 {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value);
  function approve(address spender, uint value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

contract test {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(address); // to reference 
    ERC20 token = new ERC20(); //creates new contract

    token.transferFrom(from, to, value); //call the transferFrom function of the reference contract or newly created one if thats the case.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to construct proper call code, Solidity need the following information about the function being called:

1. Name
2. Argument types
3. Return types

Call code generated by Solidity basically does no following:

1. Packs 4-byte function selector (derived from function name and argument types)
2. Pack arguments (needs to know argument types here)
3. Parse returned value (needs to know return types here)